# Why does the From field differ when I write a new email or when I reply, and how to fix it?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-mail

iPhone with iOS 16.6.1.

When I write a new mail from my iPhone, the receiver sees my name in the field From, as expected. However, when I reply to someone's mail from the same iPhone, the field From is different; it is an account name that I used a while ago. I cannot see any setting that distinguishes the From field depending on if it is a new message or a reply, and I am looking for a way to fix it.

Comment: You can delete the old email address in your Contacts.app. And delete the account in **Settings > Mail > Accounts**. Also if you tap on that email address in the email you are replying to you can change it.